# Ruby on Rails HTTPS Post Bad Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, https, bad-request

Greetings all.

My application works with a remote server. Server uses https
authorization of the certificate. I have following code to authorize and
sends request:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://db1-test.content.ertelecom.ru/")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, '443')
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
http.ca_file = File.join(File.dirname("public/certificate.pem"),
"certificate.pem")
http.start do |http|
      req =
Net::HTTP::Get.new("/cgi-bin/expr/export.get_pay_systems?partner_id=1003")
      responce = http.request(req)
      resp = responce.body
end
```

this code works well, I get the data from the server. BUT when I try to
make POST request:

```
http.start do |http|
      req =
Net::HTTP::Post.new("/cgi-bin/expr/payment_transactions.verify_order",
params)
      responce = http.request(req)
      resp = responce.body
end
```

I get an error from the server:

```
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Request header field is missing ':' separator.
```

what is that be? I tried to find a solution, but to no avail. the
Internet caught the message that it could be antivirus, but I'm on
Linux. I will be glad to any thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not filling the header data.

You could either use the Net::HTTP.post_form method to create your request or populate the form_data yourself.

post_form solution:

```
req = NET::HTTP.post_form("/cgi-bin/expr/payment_transactions.verify_order", params)
```

manual form_data population

```
req =
  Net::HTTP::Post.new("/cgi-bin/expr/payment_transactions.verify_order")
req.set_form_data(params)
```

Comment: strange... when i try use set_form_data i get:
undefined method `set_form_data=' for #<Net::HTTP::Post POST>

and when i use post_form:
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+

Comment: all works! just needed to use the following syntax:
req.set_form_data(params)