# How to write this HTTPS POST request in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, net-http

I'm pretty new in Ruby and Rails.

I want to send a HTTP POST request in my rails application, the request can be invoked by command line like:

```
   curl -X POST -u "username:password" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   --data '{"device_tokens": ["0C676037F5FE3194F11709B"], "aps": {"alert": "Hello!"}}' \
   https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/
```

The ruby code I wrote (actually it's glue code) is:

```
uri = URI('https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push')
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
    request.basic_auth 'username', 'password'
    request.body = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode({'device_tokens' => ["4872AAB82341AEE600C6E219AA93BB38B5144176037F2056D65FE3194F11709B"], "aps" => {"alert" => "Hello!"}})
    response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
    puts response.body
end
```

However, running the ruby code in Rails Console didn't give me expected result (the command line does). Can someone give me a hand? I've tried searching relevant posts and Ruby docs, however my knowledge in Ruby is not good enough to solve it.

Comment: perhaps this question will be able to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719809/ruby-on-rails-https-post-bad-request

Comment: Hi, I read the post but couldn't figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often tidier to create a little client class. I like HTTParty for that:

```
require 'httparty'

class UAS
  include HTTParty

  base_uri "https://go.urbanairship.com"
  basic_auth 'username', 'password'
  default_params :output => 'json'
  @token = "4872AAB82341AEE600C6E219AA93BB38B5144176037F2056D65FE3194F11709B"

  def self.alert(message)
    post('/api/push/', {'device_tokens' => @token, 'aps' => {"alert" => message}})
  end
end
```

Then you use it like so:

```
UAS.alert('Hello!')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'

https = Net::HTTP.new('go.urbanairship.com', 443)
https.use_ssl = true
path = '/api/push'
```