# Sending post request from rails with rest_client.. 400 Bad request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest-client, net-http

Basically, I want to send post request to a faye server. When I use curl, It works,

```
curl http://localhost:9292/faye -d 'message={"channel":"/messages/new", "data":"hello"}'
```

I can see hello in client.

but when I use http_party or the rest_client or net http, It says bad request.

```
def send

     params = {'channel' => 'faye/messages/new','data' => 'hello', "Content-type" => "application/json"}
     x = Net::HTTP::Post.new (URI.parse('http://localhost:9292/faye'))
     puts x.body

    # I tried it with http_ party too and rest_cliet.
    #  data = {
    #    channel: "messages/new",
    #    data: "hello"
    #  }
    #  RestClient.post 'http://localhost:9292/faye', :channel => 'messages/new', :data=> "hello"
    # response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: '127.0.0.1:9292/faye',messages: {"channel" => "messages/new", "data"=>"hello"})
   end
end
```

I have tried slolutions from [Submitting POST data from the controller in rails to another website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195962/submitting-post-data-from-the-controller-in-rails-to-another-website)

and [Ruby on Rails HTTPS Post Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719809/ruby-on-rails-https-post-bad-request)   but it still says bad request.

I dont know where I am making mistake. I have been pulling my hair in this for 
some days.
My ruby version is 2.2.4
rails -v => 4.2.5

**Edit:** with help from accepted answer, I update my method. Its working now.

```
require 'rest_client'
   require 'json'
   def send
     RestClient.post 'http://localhost:9292/faye', {message: {"channel" => "/messages/new", "data"=>"hello"}.to_json}, {:content_type => :json, :accept => :json}
   end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your curl example you're sending json data, but not when using Ruby. Try this

```
require "json"
RestClient.post("http://localhost:9292/faye", {
  message: {"channel" => "messages/new", "data"=>"hello"}.to_json
})
```

Comment: many many thanks man, It worked, also I found another mistake. the channel path should be
"channel" => "/messages.new".
now it works. :)